# I want to play my uploaded videos on my database one by one using javascript

Tags: php, mysql, html, video

I am having trouble with playing my uploaded videos on the database.
I want them to play one by one. I'm using the echo tag of php to call out my file/s:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_upload");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $upload_id = $row['upload_id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $url = $row['url']; 
    echo "<video loop autoplay width='1360' height='720'>
    <source src='$url' type='video/mp4'>$name</source>
    </video></a><br />";        
}
?>
```

Using this code/s my videos will play at the same time, all of them. I want them to play one by one like one in a commercial/advertising videos. I'm new to this so I need help.

Comment: <?php
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_upload");
          while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
               {
                 $upload_id = $row['upload_id'];
                 $name = $row['name'];
                    $url = $row['url']; 
    echo "<video loop autoplay width='1360' height='720'>
   <source src='$url' type='video/mp4'>$name</source>
    </video></a><br />";
    
               }
?>

Comment: what you'll want is to load the videos into an array, then when the first video ends trap the `ended` event to load and play the next video source

Comment: Are you trying to create a playlist? I think you can just reload the page after a video has ended. Redirect the page to the next video. Or just reload the next video using javascript.

Comment: yes that's what im trying to do but i dont know what exact codes i should use since im still learning and this task was given to me its a class project

Comment: could you give me some example codes that i could work with? id really appreciate it, that way it will be easier for me to continue my progress. Thank you